# How to unit-test StdDeserializer in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, kotlin, deserialization

The JSON object that is deserialized is of this format.

```
{
   "myTypes":["type-1","type-2"...]
}
```

The deserializer class is as follows.

```
class MyDeserializer: StdDeserializer<MyType>( MyType::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(jsonPareser: JsonParser?, dctx: DeserializationContext?): MyType? {
        val node: JsonNode = jsonPareser?.codec?.readTree(jsonPareser) ?: return null
        return try {
            MyType.valueOf(node.textValue().uppercase().replace('-','_'))
        }catch (e : IllegalArgumentException){
            null
        }
    }
```

I have written most of the tests but can't figure out what to do in the mentioned part.

```
class MyTypeDeserializerTest {
    @BeforeEach
    fun init() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "given string \"{0}\" is valid:  \"{1}\"")
    @MethodSource("tests")
    fun `check different parameters`(string: String, myType: MyType) {
        val myTypeDeserializer = MyTypeDeserializer()
        val deserialisedType= myTypeDeserializer.deserialize(<what do I put here?>)

        Assertions.assertEquals(myType, deserialisedType)
    }

    private companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun tests() = Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(String.format(<josn>), expectedType),
        )
    }

}
```

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a sort of **integration test** to test your code.

```
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "given string \"{0}\" is valid:  \"{1}\"")
    @MethodSource("tests")
    fun `check different parameters`(string: String, myType: MyType) {
    
        // create a jackson object mapper instance and register your own deserializer
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule().registerModule(SimpleModule().apply {
            addDeserializer(MyType::class.java, MyDeserializer())
        })    
                
        // read the serialized string into an object using your deserializer
        Assertions.assertEquals(myType, mapper.readValue<MyType>(string))
    
    }
```

The example assumed that the `jackson-module-kotlin`([Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-kotlin/2.13.3)) is available within the classpath. Alternativly you should use `mapper.readValue(serialized, MyType::class.java)` to deserialize your json and should skip adding `registerKotlinModule()` to the object mapper builder.

Comment: This is an extension function from the `jackson-module-kotlin`. Have a look at [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-kotlin/2.13.3) package.

As an alternative you may use the `mapper.readValue(serialized, MyType::class.java)` method

Comment: One more thing. Value of node with your serialized string is "myTypes" instead of type-1,type-2. How do I change the serialized for node to be correct?

Comment: My example does not reflect your above described situation correctly. I will update my answer to your concrete use case. You are using parameterized tests and i have just wrote your above mentioned json into a single string. thanks for pointing that out :)